# How do I search for conditions between rows of a data.table defined by a time lag?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of prescription records. Each row is a prescription for a single drug on a particular day. I have divided the drugs into two groups with partial overlap. I would like to identify where prescriptions have been issued from both drug groups within 3 days of each other but not include where the same drug has been issued from group 1 and 2 identifying the date of the latter drug of the pair.

An example of my data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(10)
DT <- data.table(day = sample(c(1:31), 30, replace = TRUE),
                 drug_group = sample(c(1, 2), 30, replace = TRUE),
                 drug_1 = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 30, replace = TRUE),
                 drug_2 = sample(c("A", "D", "E"), 30, replace = TRUE))
DT[drug_group == 1, drug := drug_1]
DT[drug_group == 2, drug := drug_2]
DT[, c("drug_1", "drug_2") := NULL]
setkey(DT, day)
```

so the following:

```
    day drug_group drug
 1:   2          1    B
 2:   3          1    C
 3:   4          1    B
 4:   7          2    E
 5:   8          1    A
 6:   9          2    A
 7:   9          2    D
 8:   9          1    C
 9:  10          1    A
10:  12          1    A
...
24:  22          2    D
25:  22          2    E
26:  24          1    A
27:  25          1    A
28:  26          2    D
29:  26          1    C
30:  27          1    C
```

I would like to obtain a result like this:

```
    day interaction_present
 1:   1       FALSE
 2:   2       FALSE
 3:   3       FALSE
 4:   4       FALSE
 5:   5       FALSE
 6:   6       FALSE
 ...
26:  26       TRUE
29:  29       FALSE
30:  30       FALSE
```

I am pretty sure I could do this by looping over each row in turn but I have been admonished repeatedly for using loops instead of vectorising and I wondered if this type of task was feasible without a loop? I have looked at using the data.table shift() function to set up lags but I am wary of creating too many new columns since my actual data.table is over a million rows.

Sorry if this is a trivial issue or if it has been asked before but I have been stuck on it all afternoon and I am giving up for the day!

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to make the example reproducible.

Comment: Oops, okay will remember for next time.

Comment: @iProcrastinate are just re-run your code with a `set.seed` like akrun has asked and copy and paste your results so we can check if we are doing it correctly

Comment: also, for day2 aren't drugs C,A,D within 3days of each other and also from 2 different groups? Shouldn't it be true?

similarly, day1? or are we only looking at previous 3 days

Comment: I need to identify if the condition had been met and how many times counting once per pair of rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if I am understanding your question correctly the following should work. Any changes can easily be made to the logic decisions within the function as well as the time lag `start` and `end` variables.

```
timelagadj <- function(i){

  ## this should be changed depending on what you mean by "within"
  ## 3 days. This currently goes i-3,i+3
  ## but if i-3 or i+3 doesn't exist in dayDT$day
  ## then we pull the value one above/below i-3/i+3 respectively
  start <- max(dayDT$day[i]-3,dayDT$day[1])
  start <- ifelse(dayDT$day[findInterval(start,dayDT$day)] < start,
            findInterval(start,dayDT$day)+1,
              findInterval(start,dayDT$day))
  end <- min(dayDT$day[i]+3,dayDT$day[nrow(dayDT)])
  end <- findInterval(end,dayDT$day)

  ## now we pull the relevant group ID and drug ID
  gIDs <- dayDT$groupID[start:end]
  dIDs <- dayDT$drugID[start:end]

  ## here we unlist the paste made before
  ## to group by days
  gIDs <- unlist(strsplit(gIDs,"_"))
  dIDs <- unlist(strsplit(dIDs,"_"))

  ## now we can apply our logic rule based
  ## on the criteria you mentioned

  if(length(unique(gIDs))>1){
    tmp <- unique(data.frame(gIDs,dIDs))
    if(length(unique(tmp$gIDs))!=length(unique(tmp$dIDs))) T else F

  }else F

}

dayDT <- DT[,list("drugID"=paste(drug,collapse="_"),"groupID"=paste(drug_group,collapse="_")),by=day]
res <- sapply(1:nrow(dayDT),function(m) timelagadj(m))
res <- dayDT[,list(day,"interaction_present"=res)]
```

Comment: Although the code does not exactly produce what I was expecting this is because I was not sufficiently clear about my logic requirements. However, I can fix this myself - the code above answers my question about how to vectorise the time lag search